# Parameter attributes in c#

Tags: c#, java, annotations

How can I do the following with c# attributes. Below is a snippet of Java that annotates parameters in a constructor.

```
public class Factory {
    private final String name;
    private final String value;
    public Factory(@Inject("name") String name, @Inject("value") String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

From looking at c# annotations it does not look like I can annotate parameters. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can absolutely attribute parameters:

```
public Factory([Inject("name")] String name, [Inject("value")] String value)
```

Of course the attribute has to be declared to *permit* it to be specified for parameters via `AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Parameter)`.

See [`OutAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx) and [`DefaultParameterValueAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.defaultparametervalueattribute(v=VS.100).aspx) as examples.

Comment: I was just typing this out! You're too fast for me =D

Answer (score 1):

Create an attribute class with AttributeUsageAttribute and them, use **Reflection** to inspect the parameters.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All)]
class NewAttribute : System.Attribute { }
```

[Accessing Attributes with Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)